# Representation of support of Gaussian measure by kernels of no-variance functionals

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-calculus

Let $\mu$ be a Gaussian measure on a separable Banach space $X$ and $q$ is the covariance operator of $\mu$. I am reading a proof for

$$\operatorname {supp} \mu = \bigcap_{q(f, f) = 0} \ker f =: E$$

but there is a step I don't understand. So far I understand that the intersection is over an uncountable number of sets all having measure $1$ so the real issue is showing that the "measure $1$" property doesn't get lost in the uncountable intersection.

As we have separability, we can find a dense set $\{x_n\}$ of $E^c$, thus: $\forall n\in\mathbb N~ \exists f_n:~ q(f_n,f_n) = 0$ but $f_n(x_n) \neq 0$.

Now as $\{f_n\}_n$ is a subset of all of the linear functionals having the property $q(f,f) = 0$, we obviously have

$$E = \bigcap_{q(f, f) = 0} \ker f  \subset \bigcap_{n} \ker f_n $$

What I don't understand is the other inclusion, i.e.

$$\bigcap_{n} \ker f_n  \subset E$$

I was trying to show the contrapositive, i.e. that for any $y\in E^c$ we find a $f_n$ such that $f_n(y) \neq 0$.

Using separability, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we find a $x_m$ such that $\|y-x_m\| < \epsilon$. Then

$$f_m(y) = f_m(x_m) + f_m(y-x_m)$$

Now I know that the first term is non-zero (and I could have easily set $f_n(x_n) = 1$ above). But how can I be sure that the norms $\|f_m\|$ don't grow like $1/\epsilon$ such that both $f_m(x_m) = 1$ and $\|y-x_m\| < \epsilon$ but $f_m(y) = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might be to blame for this question.  It looks very similar to something I once wrote, with the same gap.  If so, sorry!

The result is true, but the approach described will not work.  We have to choose the $f_n$ with more care.

(Indeed, suppose $x$ is outside the linear span of your $x_n$.  Note that $E$ is closed, hence so is $E+x$.  You could thus choose the functionals $f_n$ perversely using Hahn-Banach so that they all vanish on $E +x$; if it does in fact turn out to be the case that $\mu(E)=1$ then you'll still have $q(f_n, f_n)=0$.  Then $x$ is in $\bigcap_n \ker f_n$ but not in $E$.)

I think the following should work instead. Let $F = \{f \in X^* : q(f,f) = 0\}$.  Since $X$ is separable, the unit ball $B^*$ of $X^*$ is weak-* separable metrizable, hence so is $B^* \cap F$.  So pick your sequence $\{f_n\}$ to be weak-* dense in $B^* \cap F$.  Suppose $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$ and take any $f \in F$, renormalized so that $\|f\| \le 1$.  Pass to a subsequence so that $f_n \to f$ weak-*.  Then $0 = f_n(x) \to f(x)$.  Since $f$ was arbitrary we have $x \in E$.

Comment: Thanks! So, just to make sure I got this: With "weak-* separable metrizable" you just mean that $B^*$, being in a separable space, is metrizable in the weak-* topology, right? And metrizability is needed for "weak-* sequential compactness" of $(f_n)_n$ in order to be able to extract a subsequence converging weak-*.

Comment: @FasEtNefas: I mean that if $X^*$ is equipped with the weak-* topology, the subset $B^*$ is both separable and metrizable.  And I am not using weak-* (sequential) compactness here, but simply the fact that $\{f_n\}$ is weak-* dense.  Thanks to metrizability it is also sequentially dense.  So it is possible to extract a subsequence which not only converges, but converges to the given $f$.

Comment: Alright. Could you maybe provide me with a suggestion for further reading, especially on the statement "weak-* dense sequence + metrizable space = weak-* sequentially dense sequence"? I fear my textbook skips this.

Comment: The fact that $B^*$ is separable and metrizable in the weak-* topology (whenever $X$ is separable) is pretty standard; I think I first saw it in Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*.  Given this, "weak-* sequentially dense" is easy: choose a weak-* dense sequence $\{f_n\}$ (by separability) and fix a compatible metric $d$.  Given $f$, by density, for each $k$ there is an $f_{n_k}$ with $d(f,f_{n_k}) < 1/k$.  So $f_{n_k} \to f$ weak-*.

Comment: Sorry to bother again but after a careful look into Conway's book (and also Brezis) I could only find statements regarding the metrizability of the unit ball in X∗
with the weak- * -topology, but I couldn't find anything about the separability. Without that I don't see how we can choose a subsequence weak-*-dense in $B^*\cap F$ of $(f_n)_n$ in the first place.

Comment: @FasEtNefas: Well, a lazy way to see it is that by Alaoglu the unit ball is weak-* compact, and compact metric spaces are separable.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was so caught up with $X^*$ not being separable that I missed this argument.

Comment: Why do such kernels have $\mu$ measure 1?

Comment: @orange: The covariance operator $q$ is defined by $q(f,g) = \int_X fg\,d\mu$.  So if $q(f,f) = 0$ then $\int_X f^2\,d\mu = 0$, which is to say $f = 0$ $\mu$-a.e., which is to say $\mu(\ker f) = 1$.

Comment: why not as $\int fg-\int f\int g $?

Comment: @orange: Mercury Bench doesn't write it, but from context I assume that we are dealing here with a *centered* Gaussian measure.  In this case we have $\int f\,d\mu = 0$ for any continuous linear functional $f$.

Comment: Makes sense but why is this the smallest such set and why is it closed

Comment: @orange: It is clear that $F = \bigcap_{q(f,f)=0} \ker f$ is closed because it is an intersection of closed sets (recall that all the $f$ are continuous).  To see it is the smallest takes more work.  The best way I know to see it is to restrict everything to $F$, so that $q$ is now non-degenerate, and use the Cameron-Martin theorem to show that this would imply that $\mu$ has full support. [...]

Comment: Given a ball $B(x,\epsilon)$, separability guarantees there is some other ball $B(y, \epsilon/2)$ with positive measure.  Now the non-degeneracy of $q$ implies the Cameron-Martin subspace $H \subset F$ is dense, so find some $h$ very close to $x-y$ and translate the measure by $h$, which by the Cameron-Martin theorem leaves it quasi-invariant.  You can see Section 4.3 of my notes at https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03591 for some more information.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, I am trying to work out the paper exercise by exercise. Thank you for your response